# How to find the lat long from a city name

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager

I have a city name but not the lat long values for that city. How would I go about getting the lat and long values from a city name and then save it to a variable in iOS? I've seen the geo reverse coding but the examples I've seen do the opposite to what I'm looking for (they find the city name from the lat/lon).

Comment: If **reverse geocoding** is the *opposite* of what you are looking for, then what do you think what you are looking for is called?

Comment: I was trying to nudge you in the right direction. It is called **[geocoding](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLGeocoder_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLGeocoder/geocodeAddressDictionary:completionHandler:)** and Jay Gajjar was close.

Comment: @user2588945 Did you check the documentation, tried something like `geocodeAddressDictionary:completionHandler:` for example and didn't work ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a geocoder and pass in the string name:

Be sure to add CoreLocation to your project and `#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>`, alternatively, if you are using Xcode 5, module support will automatically link against the correct framework with `@import CoreLocation;`

```
NSString *city = @"New York, New York";
CLGeocoder *geocoder = [CLGeocoder new];
[geocoder geocodeAddressString:city completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        return; // Bail!
    }

    if ([placemarks count] > 0) {
        CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks lastObject]; // firstObject is iOS7 only.
        NSLog(@"Location is: %@", placemark.location);

    }
}];
```

which gives

> Location is: <+40.72377900,-73.99128900> +/- 100.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 9/24/13, 2:34:18 PM British Summer Time

I'm just logging the placemark so you get a bit more, but you can see the lat, long of New York in there.

Comment: You aren't running iOS 7 then. Try with `lastObject` instead.