# Make the map go direct to the place I want by name

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I got 2 `ViewControllers`:
In the first I got `TableView` with name of countries. 
When I click on one of the countries's cell it moves to the second `ViewControl` with `performSegueWithIdentifier` & saves the cell's name (for example: "France") in a variable outside the `ViewController`. in the seconds ViewController I got a MapKit View. I don't know how to make the map to go to "France".

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you coordinates of france?

Comment: @DharmeshKheni No, I got a lot of countries so I can't make coordinate for all of them. I want the map go to the country only by it's name, like if you type in search "France" - it will do the job.

Comment: Can [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18982535/how-to-find-the-lat-long-from-a-city-name) help you to find **lat long** by place name ? One more thing you can not directly show a place on map without getting its **lat long**. So try to find best way to get **lat long** from place name.

Comment: @TheTiger This answer is in objective-c, do you know how to compile to swift ?

Comment: @specialnoob Its very simple ... Use **. (dot)** instead of **square brackets [ ]**, **( )** to pass parameters and let **XCode** show you the intelligence and thats it. Go ahead you can do. It will take just 5 minutes for this code snippet. (y)

Comment: Well as I had little time so [here](http://pastie.org/10320006) is the **Swift** code.

Comment: @TheTiger first of all - thank you for switching it to swift! second, i posted it in the Xcode and it still doesn't show me the current country (i changed the "city" to the country i choose

Answer (score 1):

```
    - (void)performSearchWithLocationName:(NSString*)CountryName{
        //#define METERS_PER_MILE 1.344
        MKLocalSearchRequest *request =
        [[MKLocalSearchRequest alloc] init];
        request.naturalLanguageQuery = CountryName;
        request.region = _mapView.region;

        MKLocalSearch *search =
        [[MKLocalSearch alloc]initWithRequest:request];

        [search startWithCompletionHandler:^(MKLocalSearchResponse
                                             *response, NSError *error) {
            if (response.mapItems.count == 0){
                NSLog(@"No Matches");


            }
            else{

                for (MKMapItem *item in response.mapItems)
                {

                    MKPointAnnotation *annotation =
                    [[MKPointAnnotation alloc]init];
                    annotation.coordinate = item.placemark.coordinate;
                    annotation.title = item.name;
                   NSLog(@"%@", annotation.title);
                    [_mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
                    MKCoordinateRegion region;
                    region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(annotation.coordinate,0.3*METERS_PER_MILE, 0.3*METERS_PER_MILE);

                  [self.mapView setRegion:[self.mapView regionThatFits:region] animated:YES];

                }

         }

        }];
    }
//You can implement map delegate
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view{

 NSLog(@"selected annotation and it's coordinates =>%f & %f",[view.annotation coordinate].latitude,[view.annotation coordinate].longitude);


}
```

Comment: Do you have it in Swift? :)

Comment: But in this code I also need to type longitude and latitude. I want that the map will go to the country only by it's name (like in search)

Comment: You  can pass Country name to this function.

Answer (score 0):

Setp 1 : Getting latitude & longitude using location name

Setp 2 : Create the CLLocationCoordinate2D Using that latitude and longitude

Setp 3 : Create the MKCoordinateRegion

Setp 2 : Change the Mapview Region

Comment: But I got a lot of countries and I don't want to get the latitude and longitude of each one. How can I get it only by name?

Comment: So follow the steps srinivas n outlines at the time you want to display a country. Be aware, though, that looking up a country by name is an asynchronous network process that takes some time. It might take 10 seconds to come back with an answer, and if the network is having trouble, it can take a minute or more. You need to build that into your decision making process.